# Android apps always part of the OS source?

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to customize the Email app that's at packages/apps/Email in the android source. However, I noticed that it has a dependency on the OS/SDK that it's part of and is not really separate.

For ex., if I pick up the Email app from the latest master, it will run only on 4.3 android devices, and not on 4.0.x. The app uses certain features of device admin that are there only in 4.3 and is not written to work on the previous versions.

And if I take the app from 4.0.x android source then I am missing the latest and the greatest of the Email app that's in master.

Is there a reason why the apps are not maintained independently of the OS, and built to be backward compatible?

Thanks.

Comment: From a simple perspective I'd say that as new OS features are added the default set of apps are part of the OS version can make use of that feature. The cost of dev and test to ensure that new versions work on old version is probably not worth the cost to Google. Of course you are welcome to do that and it will cost you time and effort to mimic those features on the old version of the OS.

Comment: Doesn't it depend - on how many changes are based on the features of the new OS and how many otherwise? It might very be the case that it's the former, but I guess its difficult to quantify. that's why I wonder what was the original rationale Google chose that path.